# Intercepts of a crystal plane in the crystal axes?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, solid-state-physics, crystals

I was deriving the relation between $d$-the distance between between adjacent set of planes (parallel) , $a$- the side of the cell and miller indices $h,k,l$ , but while starting it took the intercepts of the axes as $\frac{a}{h} ,\frac{a}{k},\frac{a}{l}$ ? I am unable to figure out why the intercepts are like that ?

Please help .

Comment: Do you know how the Miller indices are defined?

Comment: @nasu Yes , even i got the intuition that the above occurs but i wanted to prove it .

Comment: You could just apply the definition to the plane with these intercepts. What will be the Miller indices of that plane? You should realize that Miller indices represent a family of planes and not just one. The one described by these cuts is just one possible choice of a plane with these indices.

Comment: @nasu ya , this is just one possible choice of a plane with these indices .